# Need your experience with query performance

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i have been asked to find a way to improve the following query in order to make it faster. As is it takes about 15 min to run and it deletes no rows!
If i well understand, the query deletes all duplicates rows based on a multiple column key, and it keeps only the row with the greatest data value..but i'm not so sure...

```
DELETE FROM mytable F  
WHERE f.f_elab = 'F'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable t
        WHERE f.gldgj < t.gldgj
        AND T.F_ELAB = 'F'
        AND F.GLMCU = t.GLMCU
        AND f.globj = t.globj
        AND f.glsub = t.glsub
        AND NVL(f.gmdl01,' ') = NVL(t.gmdl01,' ')
        AND NVL(f.imitm,0) = NVL(t.imitm,0)
        AND NVL(f.imlitm,' ') = NVL(t.imlitm,' ')
        AND NVL(f.articolo_lunghezza_5,' ') = NVL(t.articolo_lunghezza_5,' ')
        AND NVL(f.imdsc1,' ') = NVL(t.imdsc1,' ')
        AND NVL(f.gmr022,' ') = NVL(t.gmr022,' ')
        AND NVL(f.hfm,' ') = NVL(t.hfm,' ')
        AND NVL(f.imglpt,' ') = NVL(t.imglpt,' ')
        AND NVL(f.glsbl,' ') = NVL(t.glsbl,' ')
        AND NVL(f.gldct,' ') = NVL(t.gldct,' ')
        AND NVL(f.classe_coge,' ') = NVL(t.classe_coge,' ')
        AND NVL(f.gldoc,0) = NVL(t.gldoc,0)
        AND NVL(f.imsrp1,' ') =  NVL(t.imsrp1,' ')
        AND NVL(F.IMSRP4,' ') = NVL(t.IMSRP4,' ')
        AND NVL(f.gllt,' ') = NVL(t.gllt,' ')
        AND NVL(f.gmr030,' ') =  NVL(t.gmr030,' ')
        AND NVL(f.componente_costo,' ') =  NVL(t.componente_costo,' ')
        AND NVL(f.gmr033,' ') =  NVL(t.gmr033,' ')
        AND NVL(f.gmr034,' ') =  NVL(t.gmr034,' ')
        AND rownum<2);
```

Can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would convert this query into a SELECT and then try to optimize the plan with indexes and logic tweaks.

Comment: The `rownum<2` means it'll stop as soon as it finds a match which can improve performance; but if there are no matches then it still has to examine all of the data to determine that. What indexes do you have, how selective are they, and what does the execution plan show?

Comment: Do you have a primary key?

Comment: @Alex - I think `Exists` does that for you anyway - I would take it out

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really say if this will improve performance, but I would tackle this problem like so ...

```
DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE PRIMARY_KEY IN
(
  SELECT MAX(PRIMARY_KEY) FROM MYTABLE
  WHERE F_ELAB = 'F'
  GROUP BY 
    GLMCU,
    globj,        
    glsub,
    gmdl01,
    <... ETC ...>,
    gmr034
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1     
)
```

This assumes you HAVE a PK, of course.  It also is only useful for duplicates, not triplicates (unless you run it more than once).

There is also a question as to the records you want to keep - first in, last in?

If you have no PK and it doesn't matter which record you wish to keep you can use `RowID` instead of `PRIMARY_KEY`

Comment: Looking again at your query - it looks as though `gldgj` is your key, and the intention is to preserve the 'earliest/smallest'

Comment: Yes @Hugh, gldgj is a date field and i think the intention is to keep the row with the most recent date and to delete the duplicate rows that have all other fields identical but have a the older date

Comment: Is there any other key ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, the query now runs in 4 seconds! 
This is what i tried:

```
DELETE mytable WHERE ROWID IN 
(
SELECT ROWID  FROM 
    (
    SELECT  ROWID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY F_ELAB, GLMCU, globj, glsub, gmdl01, imitm, imlitm, articolo_lunghezza_5, imdsc1, gmr022, hfm, imglpt, glsbl, gldct , classe_coge  , gldoc , imsrp1, IMSRP4, gllt, gmr030, componente_costo , gmr033, gmr034  ORDER BY gldgj DESC ) AS rn
    FROM    mytable F 
    WHERE f.f_elab = 'F'
    )
WHERE   rn > 1
)
```

This does exactly what the first query does! and it keeps only the record with the most recent date. The only doubt i still have is about all of those fields in the PARTITION BY argument. Do i have to use the NVL as it was in the first query? or it will work the same without that even if one or more fields have the null value?